# Displaying Unicode string in Users control in Xamarin (Android)

Tags: android, visual-studio, unicode, xamarin.android, textview

Basically, i have a list of Nepali Unicode strings something like {"युनिकोड १ ","युनिकोड २","युनिकोड ३"}.

Now, Firstly, I have a text view in Xamarin (Android) and tried to set the text property using couple of methods:

1. UnicodeTextView.Text="युनिकोड १"; //direct method
2. var font = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(_activity.Assets, "kantiput.TTF");//kantiput.TTF Is a Nepali font.
   UnicodeTextView.Typeface = font;
3. var font = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(_activity.Assets, "kantiput.TTF");
   UnicodeTextView.SetTypeface(font, TypefaceStyle.BoldItalic);

and none of them worked.
When using the first option nothing was displayed, and on working with last two

---

---

and there were some BOX character visible.

For first case when i directly tried to set the value:

Before setting value:

[image]

After setting value:

[image]

Samething with the ListAdapter.

[image]

Can anyone suggest me how can we display unicode sentences in TextView, EditText, Toast ?

I want result something like this :

with TextView :

[image]

and here is the weird behavior :

[image]

and i tried all those code that are in comment too. Still didn't find any luck.

Comment: add this dependency `compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'`
 use this line for text set in textview
`textview.settext(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava("here is your textMessage"))`

Answer (score 0):

I am working in android.
In toast I checked like the following:
Toast.makeText (this, "\u0c05  \u0c06", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).Show();

For first two letters of Telugu alphabet s. It worked.

If you have the font file you can obtain unicode  codes for the various glyphs in the online software available at

```
 https://opentype.js.org/index.html
```

Under page glyph inspector.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code, the first direct method `UnicodeTextView.Text="युनिकोड १";` works fine by my side both with single `TextView` or `TextView` in `ListView`.

Or you may try this code:

```
if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
{
    UnicodeTextView.Text = Android.Text.Html.FromHtml("युनिकोड १", Android.Text.FromHtmlOptions.ModeLegacy).ToString();
}
else
{
    UnicodeTextView.Text = Android.Text.Html.FromHtml("युनिकोड १").ToString();
}
```

Comment: Hi Grace ..still it didn't work on my end. I ll add one more screen shot that shows some weird behavior ..in VisualStudio layout file the unicode string seem to be ok and in code the value is assigned as expected.but when it comes to emulator, it wont be rendered.. hope you could share your code to me....

Comment: @ShresthaGanesh, the code is exactly like yours, simply `UnicodeTextView.Text="युनिकोड १";`, renders well...Did you try any real device or change another emulator?